# Linked List Implementation in C. Looking for feedback

Tags: beginner, c, linked-list

I am new to C programming and DSA. This is my implementation of a Linked List. I am looking for feedback and tips to improve the code design.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Function declarations
node *createList(node *head, int number);
void add(node **head, int number);
void append(node *head, int number);
void insertAt(node **head, int number, int position);
int listLength(node *head);
void printList(node *head);
void unload(node *head);

int main(void) {
    node *list = NULL;

    // Create a list
    list = createList(list, 31);

    // Test fire
    add(&list, 100);
    append(list, 9009);
    insertAt(&list, 707, 5);
    insertAt(&list, 130211, 3);
    
    // Print the list
    printf("List: ");
    printList(list);        
    printf("Total length: %d\n", listLength(list));
    
    unload(list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}

// Helper functions
node *createList(node *head, int number) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for the list.");
        free(new_node);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (head != NULL) {
        printf("List already created.\n");
        free(new_node);
        return head;
    }

    new_node->number = number;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

void add(node **head, int number) {
    if (*head == NULL || head == NULL) {
        printf("Underflow.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
       printf("Could not allocate memory for the node.\n"); 
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->number = number;
    new_node->next = *head; 
    *head = new_node;
}

void append(node *head, int number) {
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for the node.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    new_node->number = number;
    new_node->next = NULL;  

    for (node *tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        if (tmp->next == NULL) {
           tmp->next = new_node; 
           break;
        }        
    }    
}

void insertAt(node **head, int number, int position) {
    if (*head == NULL || head == NULL) {
       printf("Underflow.\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for the node.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_node->number = number;

    node *tmp = *head;
    node *tmp2 = NULL;
    int cur = 0;
    
    // Traverse the list till the position
    while (tmp != NULL && cur < position) {
       cur++; 
       tmp2 = tmp;    
       tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp2->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = tmp;
}

int listLength(node *head) {
    int length = 0;
    for (node *tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

void printList(node *head) { 
    for (node *tmp = head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        printf("%d ", tmp->number);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void unload(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    free(head->next);
    free(head); 
}
```

Comment: In the future please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Although I did not change the code based on the improvements suggested by the reviewer, I will keep in mind the rules and regulations of this website.

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order:

1. Use `snake_case` for functions, `PascalCase` for types.
2. Use descriptive function names. (What does "add" do?)
3. Use helper functions for commonly-repeated operations, like allocating nodes and print-an-error-and-exit.
4. Your `append` doesn't work for empty list (head == NULL).
5. Because so many of your functions end up wanting `node **`, you might want to either create a separate list-header type, or maintain a dummy node in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please explain the last point? Do you suggest using typedef on `node **`? The `append` function is inserting a node at the end of the list. Hence, it should avoid the case when `HEAD == NULL`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Right now you are using pointer-to-node as the type of your list-head. Something like `Node * head = NULL;` or `Node * head = create_node(123);`. Because you need to modify the head pointer in order to insert/delete the first node, you wind up having to pass `&head` to almost all  the functions. One way to avoid this is to create a separate "list" type that is not the same as `Node` for list variables:  `List * head = create_list();`. Another way to avoid it would be to maintain a dummy node at the start of the list, so that head was never `==NULL`.

Comment: As for `append`, what happens if you append to an empty list? IMO, append([], 10) -> [10].

Comment: I understand better now. Thank you for your time and feedback.

Comment: I would add to use descriptive function names, and also consider commenting what exactly the function does. Afaik, PascalCase is not really a standard naming convention for C, but is a reasonably good suggestion. A sentinel (dummy node) is also a good suggestion.

Comment: Good to have a uniform style. yet "Use snake_case for functions, PascalCase for types.' is not a style I would recommend.  IAC, best to follow one's group's style guide.